# ESP32 GPIO not turning on MOSFET completely

Tags: mosfet, esp32

I have designed a circuit that will switch on a 12V siren through a IRF540N MOSFET. The siren positive is connected to ST-3 (12V), while the negative is connected to ST-4 (SIREN-12V). A flyback diode is used for protection.

The IRF540N has a gate threshold voltage of 2V to 4V. I am using an ESP32 to turn the siren on and off via the MOSFET. The output current of IO 13 of the ESP32 is 33mA and the voltage is around 3.2V, so this should be enough to turn the MOSFET on. However, this 12V siren when activated sounds very quiet.

When I apply the 3V3 voltage from the ESP32 to the gate of the MOSFET, the siren then sounds as expected (loud).

Why is there is a difference in the loudness of the siren? The MOSFET should turn on when GPIO 13 is high but it sounds like the is only turning on the gate slightly.

[image]

Comment: According to the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/67691.pdf) that MOSFET just barely reaches it's Miller plateau at 4V Vgs.

Comment: schematic for connection looks right.  still worth double-checking you have mosfet connected to correct leg.  Another thing to be aware of is that current supplied is proportional to current through gate - ditch the 10K pulldown (possibly for a 500k) and try again.  so close to the threshold, every piece counts.

Comment: @Abel - there is essentially zero o current through the gate. It is controlled by gate voltage. Your idea of increasing the pulldown value is good though.

Comment: yup almost but not quite.  there might also be dynamics at play depending on on/off frequency.  per post, it works at 3.3 but not at 3.2 so if he can just get that 3.2 a bit higher it might work.  hopefully yanking a resistor would be cheap enough to try.

Comment: @Abel silly question but why would the 500k ohm resistor work ?

Comment: @Abel I understand increaing the pull down from 10K to 500K will result in more current flowing through the gate and not the pull down but MOSFET are dependent on voltage not current so either way the voltage will not increase, however I know you have more experience than me so can you explain why increasing the resistance will help?

Comment: if 3.3V is reduced to 3.2V over drawing current through mystery load and 3.2V to ground via 10k pull (gate current neglected).  If mystery load is resistor (bad assumption but rolling with it), it's 312.5 Ohms.  To lose .1% (.0033V) over mystery load and 99.9% over pull, pull=3.3*.999/(.0033/312.5) =~300k.  add fudge to 500k.  Or as my gut said: if it loses 1/30 on current through 10k, x50 to get it below 1/1000.

Comment: in truth we don't know how much you would have to increase it.  start with infinity (removal) and see if it works first.  if it doesnt, no resistor increase will help you.

Comment: @Abel - the reason increasing the resistance will help (very slightly) is that it will reduce the voltage drop in the output stage of the ESP32. Nothing at all to do with current sharing between the resistor and the gate.

Comment: @KevinWhite I assumed Abel was referring to the mystery load as the internal output resistance of the ESP32?

Comment: I have good luck using the IRLZ44N with ESPs.

Comment: @dandavis its 2am over here, I am reading the Vgs and Id graph right. 3.3V looks like a drain current of 15A?????

Comment: Sounds right. I can PWM a couple amps of 12v LED strip and the bare TO220 is basically
 room temp, even being driven right from GPIO to gate.

Comment: @dandavis just tried the IRLB8743PbF, it also works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gate threshold voltage is not that at which the device is fully turned on - it means that it is just starting to conduct (typically 250uA).
[image]

Usually there is a chart showing the drain current versus gate voltage - in this device you can see that at 3.3V a typical device is only just starting to conduct. There will also be significant differences between individual devices, one might start at 2V and another at 4V. It will also change with temperature.

In order to pass a high current you usually need 10V for many MOSFETs or 5V for those referred to as Logic Level MOSFETs.

[image: IRF540 transfer characteristics]

You don't say how much current the siren requires. If it requires more than a few hundred millAmps you will need a  level shifter to create a logic signal of at least 5V and a suitable MOSFET.

For currents up to a few hundred millAmps you may be able to find a low gate threshold MOSFET that will function with 3.3V drive, or use a bipolar transistor to drive the siren.

[IRF540 Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stmicroelectronics_cd00003275-1205438.pdf)

Comment: But when I connect the 3V3 directly to the gate input from the EPS32 3V3 (pin1) the siren emits a far louder (normal) sound. Just confused why the pin1 works but not IO13

Comment: Measure the voltage when driven from the ESP32 and when connected directly to 3.3V. The transfer curve is very steep at that point and even a few 10's of millivolts will make a difference.

Comment: @Joey [This datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) for ESP32 lists the minimum high level output voltage as 0.8 * VCC. When the MOSFET is barely conducting small changes in Vgs can have large effect.

Comment: I see now. I never thought these mosfets are that sensitive. Gees, this makes a lot of sense now. Thank a mil!

Comment: Current transmitted is approximately proportional to the very tiny current drawn through the gate.  Because the slope is extreme, we usually look at it as an on/off.  However when it's barely conducting that you can observe the behavior - small increases to the voltage produce small increases to the gate current.  Gate current was tiny to begin with so it's not negligible as a percentage, and so affects the transmitted current in a big way.

Comment: @Abel - you are completely wrong. The current into the gate is purely leakage and has nothing to do with the current passed by the drain. MOSFETs are voltage driven.

Comment: Whether I'm wrong depends on whether IGS is approximately increasing with a constant slope between VGS 4.5V to 6V on that graph.  While I haven't measured it precisely myself, the model did make sense as an explanation of why that slope exists and so I've preached as it was preached before to me.

Comment: @Abel - the gate current and the drain current are both related to gate voltage but one does not cause the other.  Please read about the way MOSFETs function and you will understand.

Comment: thanks for confirming the accuracy of the model.  cause and effect however, I'll leave as a matter of faith to rationalize observed correlations and keep my understanding (which was developed from lectures and that literature) the way it was.

Comment: @Abel - I think you must have misinterpreted the information. I cannot believe that any book would publish that the drain current was related to gate current and only an incompetent lecturer would teach that.